# How can I dynamically create checkboxes based on query results in my Web API MVC app?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I need to create a "virtual" CheckedListbox (a bunch of checkboxes in a container) - that is, N checkboxes based on the results of a SQL Server query. I have placeholder html where bogus checkboxes are currently being placed on the page:

```
<div class="container" name="unitsCheckboxDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />
</div>
```

...but I need to create the checkboxes in response to the result set instead. The html above is in the \Views\Home\Index.cshtml page, so I assume the "code-behind" belongs in the \Controllers\HomeController.cs file, but I don't know what to do there. Currently I just have the default/boilerplate code there:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    . . .
```

I hope I can do something like this:

```
Page_Load()
{
    DataTable dt = GetUnits();
    unitsCheckBoxDiv.DataSource = dt;
}
```

...or more realistically more like so:

```
Page_Load()
{
    DataTable dt = GetUnits();
    foreach (string unit in dt)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new Checkbox();
        cb.Value = unit;
        unitsCheckBoxDiv.AddHTMLElement(cb);        
    }
}
```

...but I don't know how to make this vague idea more concrete.

### UPDATE

I think I'm on the right track implementing Prasad Raja's answer, but with this code:

HomeController.cs:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebAppRptScheduler.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
            SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(SQL.SelectUnitsQuery, CommandType.Text, null);
            ViewBag.Units = dtable;
            return View();
        }

    . . .
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@using System.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report Scheduler";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Report Scheduler</h1>

    DataTable ds = ViewBag.Units as DataTable;
    var rows = from x in ds.AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
        unit = x.Field<string>("unit")
    };
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Configure One Unit/Report pair at a time</h2>
        <h4>Select a Unit</h4>
        @foreach (var item in rows)
        {
            <input id="ckbx_@(item.unit)" type="checkbox" value="@item.unit" />
            @item.unit <br />
        }
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

...I get this runtime error (it compiles, although it says "Compilation Error"):

[image]

### UPDATE 2

By moving the code out of the div and into the code block (a sensible move):

```
@using System.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report Scheduler";

    DataTable ds = ViewBag.Units as DataTable;
    var rows = from x in ds.AsEnumerable()
               select new
               {
                   unit = x.Field<string>("unit")
               };
}
```

...I can get further, but I still see no checkboxes on the page:

[image]

### UPDATE 3

It turns out it was a dumb oversight on my part (I would say, "a rookie mistake" but I'm no rookie). After changing this line in the Controller:

```
SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(SQL.SelectUnitsQuery, CommandType.Text, null);
```

...to this:

```
dtable = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(SQL.SelectUnitsQuery, CommandType.Text, null);
```

...it works fine (there was nothing to loop over, so no wonder no checkboxes were generated).

Comment: The code in the last 2 snippets is web forms, not MVC. Have you tagged this correctly?

Comment: That's just pseudocode; I don't really have that code; I don't know what to do, just making a wild guess.

Comment: What is you query returning - just a list of strings? What you have shown is a bit vague, but in the GET method - `IEnumerable<string> model = your query; return View(model);` and in the view `@model IEnumerable<string> @foreach(var item in Model) { <input type="checkbox" ..../> }`

Comment: Yeah, it's a simple list of string.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon did /*dtable = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(SQL.SelectUnitsQuery, CommandType.Text, null);*/ returning the data first ? if its returning it  10001% should work with your example....

Comment: Yes, I marked your answer correct; see my final update above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple example to you

**COntroller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
            dtable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dtable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

            // adding few data to table
            dtable.Rows.Add(1, "Prasad");
            dtable.Rows.Add(2, "Raja");
            dtable.Rows.Add(3, "Hemenath");
            dtable.Rows.Add(4, "Rajesh");
            dtable.Rows.Add(5, "Suresh");
            dtable.Rows.Add(6, "Daniel");
            ViewBag.Units = dtable;
            return View();
        }
```

**View**

```
@using System.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";


    DataTable ds = ViewBag.Units as DataTable;
    var rows = from x in ds.AsEnumerable()
               select new
               {
                   id = x.Field<int>("ID"),
                   name = x.Field<string>("name")
               };
}
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>
        Select your favourite Name</h4>
    @foreach (var item in rows)
    {  
        <input id="chk_@(item.name)"   type="checkbox"  value="@item.id"   />
        @item.name <br />  
    }
</div>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is going to work eventually, I think, but please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use model and query db from controller. It's considered a very bad practice in ASP.NET MVC to query the database right from the view (unlike how it is for ASP.NET Webforms).

Controller :

```
    public DataTable MockDataTable
    {
        get
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("CheckBoxes");

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Alex", "Hello" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Alex", "World" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Alex", "Etc" });

            return dt;
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // here you do your db query
        DataTable dt= MockDataTable;

        // convert it to List<string>
        List<string> result = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
            .Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("CheckBoxes")).ToList();

        return View(result);
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

<div class="container" name="unitsCheckboxDiv">
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
         <input type="checkbox" />@item<br />
     }
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get why the View would be that way (different from what I have in Update and Update 2" and, indeed, it fails with, "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.DataTable', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'."

Comment: Why do you need to pass the entire `DataTable` when your question was: "How can I dynamically create checkboxes based on query results in my Web API MVC app?". I don't see how it is related to DataTable at all.

Comment: That's where the contents of the checkboxes come from.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon updated my answer. The less business logic is executed in View, the more lightweight objects are used there - the better.

Answer (score 1):

```
This classes/ structs need to be in /Models folder.
Use struct opposed to class as it is lightweight and suitable in your case. Also except we have MVVM situation of two way data binding, we might just want to read so public {set; } is unnecessary.

public struct CheckBoxViewModel
{
    public CheckBoxViewModel(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    internal CheckBoxViewModel(DataRow row)// because I assume you know and will pass the correct Data from DataTable, this constructor might reduce some extra code.
    {
        this.Name = row["Name"] + "";
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
public static class common
{
    public static IEnumerable<CheckBoxViewModel> GetList()
    {
        var list = new List<CheckBoxViewModel>();
        IDbCommand dbc = db.CreateCommand(); //db is your connection a static one.
        using (var r = dbc.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var cbvm = new CheckBoxViewModel(reader.GetString(0));// assuming 0 is the index of your column
                list.Add(cbvm);
            }

        }
        return list;
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(common.GetList());
}

Now in your view,
@model IEnumerable<CheckBoxViewModel>
<div class="container" name="checkboxList">
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
         <input type="checkbox" />@item.Name<br />
     }
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that DataTable is heavier than DataReader and if you just need to read, always use DataReader instead of DataTable

Comment: I forgot to mention that DataTable is heavier than DataReader and if you just need to read, always use DataReader instead of DataTable

Answer (score -1):

Update:

@B. Clay Shannon, it seems you didn't have the clear concept of the MVC, I would suggest you reading [ASP.NET MVC Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) from part 1 to part 6 first, then then modify your codes as following

First of all, you will need a ViewModel to be created under the ViewModels folder for your View Page

```
public class CheckBoxViewModel
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

Let's go to Index() of HomeController, all you need to do is just to put your query result into the CheckBoxViewModel, I don't know your query so, I will assume it is just list of strings like your said:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var checkBoxViewModel = new IList<CheckBoxViewModel>();
       foreach(var item in myDbEntities.Table.ToList())
       {
         checkBoxViewModel.add(new CheckBoxViewModel{
         Name = item.Name
         Description = item.Description
         });
       }
       return View(checkBoxViewModel);
    }
```

Secondly, go to your View Page I assume it is Home/Index based on your question.

Add this line at the top of your View Page

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProjectNamespace.ViewModels.CheckBoxViewModel>
```

After that, you just loop your result and create the checkboxes

```
@foreach(var cb in model)
{
  <input type="checkbox" id="@cb.Name" name="@cb.Name" >@item.Description<br/>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow; but where/how does the data get to the ViewModel?

Comment: Inside the foreach loop in the Action Method, you can put your query result into the ViewModel like I wrote above. You already have the query result right?

Comment: This will not work at all. Its creating `name` attributes which have no relationship to the model so model binding will fail and even if it didn't, all have a value attribute which is `value="false"` irrespective of whether the checkboxes are checked or not, they all post back false.

Comment: @StephenMuecke,  Thanks for pointing out the value in checkbox, I would modify my answer. but there is no model mentioned in the question I think

Comment: I think the question is about to create a list of checkboxes, so I don't think you need to focus on what the viewmodel is, it is just an example

Comment: by the way, may i know why was my answer being down voted even I updated it ?

Comment: Browse-by downvoters rarely leave their calling card or an explanatory note.